# Display JSON Array as html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to display my JSON array which i got from the PHP server as list in HTML. The code I used loops through the array, but when i replace the array with the variable it does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
  //Phonegap ready
  onDeviceReady();
 });

 var ownproducts = $('#ownproducts');

 $.ajax({
  url: 'MYURL',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  timeout: 5000,
  success: function(data, status){
   $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
    var products = '<br>'+item.item;
         var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('body');
    var json = { items:  ['Banana','Cherry','Apple','Strawberry','Pear','Pineapple'] };
    $(json.items).each(function(index, item) {
     ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text(item));
    });

    
   
    ownproducts.append(products);
   });
  },
  error: function(){
     ownproducts.text('Error Message');
  }
 });
});
```

So i get a JSON file containing data from my database, item.item contains an array but when i replace this:

```
var json = { items:  ['Banana','Cherry','Apple','Strawberry','Pear','Pineapple'] };
```

for:

```
var json = { items:  item.item };
```

or:

```
var json = { items:  products };
```

it does not work (not displaying anything javascript related).

EDIT:
I try to get some items from my database through PHP

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

require 'config.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($url,$username,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$userid = $_GET['userID'];


mysqli_select_db($con, $database);

$sql = "SELECT shoppingListID AS id, shoppingListUserID AS userid, shoppingCheckBox AS checkbox, shoppingItem AS item, shoppingDate AS date
FROM shoppinglist
WHERE shoppingListUserID='$userid'
ORDER BY shoppingDate DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysqli_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

the ShoppingItem field contains an array like `["Tomatos","Apples","Mangos","Bananas"]` the SQL returns multiple shoppinglists from a single user, I want to display the shoppinglists on cards with the items of each list in an html list.

Anyone any suggestions? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct JSON from the database? Does the `item` key exist? Do you get any erors in the console?

Comment: Why not do `$.each(json.items, function(index, item) {` instead of `$(json.items).each(function(index, item) {`

Comment: Also, you should not use `item` twice since they are nested loops

Comment: @Cristy, i added my PHP file, item is an array from the database.

Comment: @VIDesignz i tried '$.each(json.items, function(index, item) {' doesn't make a difference. I did rename 'item' to 'itemarray' but no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suppose that your JSON endpoint does in fact return the right data -- in this case visiting what you"ve labeled `MYURL` generates (I believe!) the text:

```
jsoncallback({"items":["Banana","Cherry","Apple","Strawberry","Pear","Pineapple"]})
```

Then we can move on to your logic, which consists in this callback function:

```
function (data, status) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var products = "<br>" + item.item;
        var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo("body");
        var json = {
            items: ["Banana", "Cherry", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Pear", "Pineapple"]
        };
        $(json.items).each(function (index, item) {
            ul.append($(document.createElement("li")).text(item));
        });
        ownproducts.append(products);
    });
}
```

What is the problem here? There are a lot. The first is that you should probably not be iterating over `data`, since that is not your array. Instead you should be iterating over `data.items`.

The second is that you should probably just be creating the HTML rather than creating a ton of DOM stuff. You can use vanilla JS's `Array.prototype.map` or `Array.prototype.join` functions rather than delegating this to JQuery: it is a part of the JS spec that this is sufficient:

```
function (data, status) {
    var html = '<ul><li>' + data.items.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
    $(html).appendTo('body');
}
```

Comment: That's not really the best way to add nodes either, Attaching them is the expensive bit, best to do it outside the loop. See http://allthingscraig.com/blog/2012/09/28/best-practice-appending-items-to-the-dom-using-jquery/ and http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2281-jquery-appends-multiple-elements-using-efficient-document-fragments.htm

Comment: First of all Thanks for the quick reply. I am just starting using JavaScript, so i don't really know what's the best way of doing things. if I understand you correctly you say i can replace: the 'function (data, status){}' with your 'data.items.join' function?

Comment: @StefSpakman Yes, the second "box" is a drop-in replacement for the first "box" of code (which came from your post): they both define anonymous functions. My general recommendation if you are "just starting" is to understand that there is not very much "magic" in JavaScript. Learn the different types of things, which you can interrogate with `typeof`: `typeof "x" == "string"`, `typeof function(){} == "function"`, etc. Learn the [environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) too.

Comment: @StefSpakman also [Mozilla's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) is really good.

Comment: @CRDrost Thank you, I tried it the way you showed and like this:     `function(data, status){
   $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
    //var products = "<br>" + item.itemarray;
    var products = '<ul><li>' + item.itemsarray.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
    
   
    ownproducts.append(products);
   });
  }`  But no succes, nothing is displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: @StefSpakman That is not the way I showed. Please compare what you wrote to the second box above. Your mistakes include: (1) you wrote `$.each`; I didn't. (And I told you not to!) (2) You wrote a comment until the end of the line which probably breaks everything; I didn't. (3) You wrote a `"<br>"`; I didn't. (4) You wrote `item.itemarray` (nonsense?); I didn't. (5) You wrote `item.itemsarray` (different nonsense?); I didn't. (6) You wrote `ownproducts.append(products)`; I didn't (What the bloody crap is `ownproducts`?)

Comment: @CRDrost, in the block from my previous comment I tried to combine your code with the code I already had. I also swapped the complete `function (data,status)` with your suggestion but with no succes. I think the array I created are faulty, due to time constraint (it is for an school project) I decided to use a different approach without arrays which is going great. Thanks for your help, the links you provided are really helpful. btw `ownproducts` is a stupid div class where the JavaScript will be placed.